# How to catch PowerShell function call from c#

Tags: c#, .net, function, powershell, overriding

I need to catch PowerShell function call from created powershell host and override it. How does it possiable?

```
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.LanguageMode = PSLanguageMode.FullLanguage;
iss.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "TestModule.psm1" });
Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
rs.Open();
Pipeline pl = rs.CreatePipeline();
pl.Commands.AddScript("TestFunction testParam");
var res = pl.Invoke();
rs.Close();
```

My task is to dynamicly override TestFunction, witch locates in TestModule, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a cmdlet (in your c# code) with the name "TestFunction" and add it to the runspace configuration like this:

```
 rs.RunspaceConfiguration.Cmdlets.Append(New CmdletConfigurationEntry("testfunction", GetType(TestFuncitonCmdlet), Nothing))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But can I change RunspaceConfiguration atfer opening Runspace?

Comment: Absolutely.  At least I know you can change the cmdlets collection on it.  I do it in hosts I've written to provide cmdlets which interact with the host in special ways.